# Closest <li> shows undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm making a bookmarking app and I want to target the and get the `id` of closest `li` inside tasks `ul` for a specific purpose.I tried this code but it is not working. hope you guys help me out

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#clicker").click(function(){
    var id = $("#tasks").closest("li").attr("id");
    alert(id);
  });

});

</script>

<h1><a id="clicker" href="#">Click Me</a></h1>

<ul id="tasks">
  <li id="4">Apples</li>
  <li id="3">Oranges</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.I never expected this kind of response.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You may want to select one of the below answer as accepted ans.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.fn.closest` is not designed to target the closest element matching but the closest **ancestor** (see doc : http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

What you have to do is to select a children there :

```
$("#clicker").click(function(){
    var id = $("#tasks").children("li").attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try:

```
var id = $("#tasks > li:first").attr("id");
```

We used:

1. JQuery's [parent > child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector to select all `li` items under
   `#tasks` list.
2. And then used [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to select first `li` from all list.

Answer (score 0):

`closest` selects the closest parent of the element, not the closest element, you can use `find` or `children` method, if you want to find the first `li` element, you can filter the result using `:first` selector or `first` method;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clicker").click(function(){
    var id = $("#tasks").find("li:first").attr("id");
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

Comment: WTF !? I wasted 2 hours for this :(
Thanks a lot man.Thanks a lot !! :)